# Is there any way to get a direct pointer to a Java array via JNI?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I need to get a pointer containing the direct memory address of a Java array, via JNI, without invoking some sort of copying (ie direct access).

GetArrayElements returns a pointer to a copied array - I need to be able to modify an int[] on the Java layer directly from a the native layer.

Casting from a `jintArray` to an `int*` returns the memory address successfully, but I'm not sure if this is particularly stable...?

Is there anything I can do here...?

Comment: So you deliberately want functionality that will result in memory corruption on JVMs using GCs that don't support pinning and therefore have to implement the available functions with copying? `GetPointerToArrayOrToArbitraryMemoryPositionThatMayHoldOtherValidObjects` was probably too long for the implementers.

Comment: Just remembered something. You can actually use `GetPrimitiveArrayCritical` - that means that no GC may run and you have to adhere to several restrictions (please read and understand them before doing this), but it'll work, as long as the primitive representation in Java is equivalent to the one in C++. If not there's nothing you can do to get around copying.

Comment: Thanks for the advice:) I don't get your first comment, surely allowing read-write access to Java allocated memory from a native layer won't cause corruption unless the gc occurs and recycles the memory for other uses (the array like is like a global buffer property and all gc occurs when the Native based object falls out of scope so surely the array memory will stay stable until then?). Thanks for the GetPrimitiveArrayCritical solution - I'll have a look:) Is there any way to create an int[] pointing directly to natively alloced memory..? Regards, Steve

Comment: If the GC doesn't allow pinning (if it did GetArrayElement wouldn't copy stuff around), it means that there's no guarantee that the int[] object is still at the same place after a GC (and obviously native pointers aren't updated contrary to java references). Which means that if you write to that position after a GC you overwrite foreign memory. You can use ByteBuffers as Peter Lawrey says - that goes around these problems by allocating the memory outside the GC heap.

Comment: Thanks. To be honest I haven't had to delve into VM before so its a bit of a learning curve;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an IntBuffer using direct memory (with native byte order). In JNI you can use the address as a pointer. In Java you have to use the get() and put().

Comment: Accessing the ByteBuffer from JNI: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/jni-14.html#GetDirectBufferAddress .

Answer (score 3):

Maybe. There are methods you can call that might give you a direct pointer to the Java memory, but that depends on the capabilities of the JVM.

From http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/objtypes.html#4099 :

> The JNI supports a family of Get/ReleaseArrayElements functions
>   (including, for example, Get/ReleaseIntArrayElements) that allow the
>   native code to obtain a direct pointer to the elements of primitive
>   arrays. Because the underlying garbage collector may not support
>   pinning, the virtual machine may return a pointer to a copy of the
>   original primitive array.

Note that you need to release the pointer when you're through with it.

**EDIT:**

In JDK 1.3, the functions [Get/ReleasePrimtiveArrayCritical()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetPrimitiveArrayCritical) were added to obtain a direct pointer even if the JVM does not support pinning.

```
"These restrictions make it more likely that the native code will 
obtain an uncopied version of the array, even if the VM does not 
support pinning. For example, a VM may temporarily disable garbage 
collection when the native code is holding a pointer to an 
array obtained via GetPrimitiveArrayCritical."
```

However, you're expected to release the pointer as soon as possible, and there are restrictions on your interactions with the JVM.

An alternative, if you have frequent but sparse interactions with a large array, is to get only small regions in the array, with [GetArrayRegion()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp6212) functions.

Comment: Thanks bro. I've been using those functions but on the specific platform I'm using they return a pointer to a copy of the array. Alternatively, is there a way I can make a Java int[] point directly to a native array?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is getting its address and set one pointer to it with **GetDirectBufferAddress** method. You can find more information below link:

```
double * cArr = (double *)((char *)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(inpObject));
```

[GetDirectBufferAddress example for a complex object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707653/how-do-i-call-multiple-data-types-from-getdirectbufferaddress-in-jni)