# Is there any way to encourage Java to pin native arrays for JNI rather than copy them?

Tags: java-native-interface

Using Java 1.8 on Linux. I've got some JNI code calling GetIntArrayElements and GetDoubleArrayElements. I would really like to benefit from pinning and returning the pointer, but I am not. I am looking at the possibility of complying with the rules for the 'Critical' functions.

This is clearly related to [Is there any way to get a direct pointer to a Java array via JNI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557804/is-there-any-way-to-get-a-direct-pointer-to-a-java-array-via-jni).

However, what I'm asking here is, 'in the current OpenJDK implementation, is pinning ever supported? If so, what circumstances enable and disable it?'

Comment: If you don't find a satisfactory answer, consider [java.nio.Buffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html) as an alternative.

Comment: I was able to restructure the code to use the 'Critical' functions which happily didn't copy. It took some rearranging. The Buffer alternative has other issues that I'm not (yet) prepared to confront.

Comment: How did you rearrange your code to get the critial functions working without copying ?